# How do I set up my Sharepoint blog correctly?

Tags: asp.net, .net, sharepoint, web, sharepoint-2013

I would like to set up my Sharepoint blog by different categories,

**Example :**

> Category-all = Displays all blog post regardless of which category I choose when I post.
>
> Category-2 = Filters away every post but post with the category-2.

How do I go about it? Is this possible without code ?

Im currently trying to fix a blog that has several post to it already, kinda migrate the content to relevant categories but also keep them in a main category like all-posts. The current blog does not filter content. How would i go about it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is totally possible without code.

Your Blog content is per default saved in a list called "Posts". This list has several views pre defined.

Create a new view based on "All posts". Now add the a filter for `Category is not equal to 2`.
Then name it something like "NotCategory2" and save it.

Now you have a ListView for All Posts and one for all posts except Category 2 posts.

Hit your homepage, where your blog is displayed again and click edit page. Now edit the Listview webpart, where your blogposts are displayed and select the View "NotCategory2".

Done.